# How to 'make' an multi-digit integer value from single digits held in an array (VB.NET)

Tags: arrays, vb.net, integer

I have a large array of single digit integers (0 - 9) and I would like to turn a subset of the values into a single integer value. For example:

```
Array(0) = 4
Array(1) = 2
Array(2) = 1
Array(3) = 6
Array(4) = 7
Array(5) = 4
Array(6) = 8
Array(7) = 2
Array(8) = 9
Array(9) = 0
```

I would like the then make a number using (for example) array indexes 4,5 and 6;

```
NewInt = 748
```

The only way i can see of doing this is making a string and then an integer (as in CInt(Cstr(Array(5) & Array(6)...)) but this seems needlessly slow. The whole point of what I'm doing is about speeding things up.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at this.

```
    Dim nums() As Integer = {4, 2, 1, 6, 7, 4, 8, 2, 9, 0}

    Dim ans As Long = 0L
    Dim useNums() As Integer = {4, 5, 6}

    For Each idx As Integer In useNums
        ans = (ans * 10L) + nums(idx)
    Next
```